# User add and shell script with password

Tags: bash, useradd

I know how to use the useradd comand but would like to make a shell script to automate the process so how would I put the users input to the password part which is a dialog presented after I have entered the comand.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-force-users-to-change-passwords/ and update your question if you can not figure it out from those links.

Comment: Use the `adduser` command instead?

Answer (score 0):

This should make it

```
#!/bin/bash
#Run ./x.sh username password
crypting=`perl -e 'printf("%s\n", crypt($ARGV[0], "password"))' "$2"`
useradd -m -p $crypting -s /bin/bash $1
```

I made something like this a while ago, when I was bored

```
#!/bin/bash
#Run ./y.sh username password
crypting=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $2)
randomid=$(echo $[ 1000 + $[ RANDOM % 10000000 ]]) 
mkdir /home/$1
echo "$1:$crypting:16760:0:99999:7:::" >> /etc/shadow
echo "$1:$crypting:$randomid:$randomid:$1:/home/$1:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd
```